# C++ (not C++11) Best way to release array in very large methods

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++03, c++98

I have to modify a very large method with many possible execution flows. The modification involves to allocate a char array in the heap using `new`. I want to be sure that this array is released properly, but I want to avoid the need of do the `delete[]` in all the possible execution flows. In addition, I want to make something "cleaner" for this purpose to avoid future bugs.

I have thought to alloc the array with `new` and then wrap it into a local `std::vector` (but keeping the reference to the raw pointer, since the method uses this reference intensively) and let the wrapper delete the raw pointer when it is out of scope.

Here I attach an example. The purpose of this example is to show the kind of operations that are peformed with the raw pointer.

```
char *rawPtr = new char[1024];
std::vector wrapper(rawPtr, rawPtr + 1024); // <= Does it assure that rawPtr will be released properly?
...
for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    rawPtr[i] = ...;

rawPtr += sizeof(...);
...
rawPtr -= ...;
if(...)
    return ...;

return ...;
```

So, my question is if I can be sure that the `rawPtr` will be released properly regardless program failures, exceptions, incoming `return` statements etc.

PD.: I cannot use `C++11`, the most similar thing I have to a smart pointer is `auto_ptr` and this uses `delete`, not `delete[]`.

Comment: Are you familiar with the term RAII? If so, what's your question?

Comment: Make your own RAII wrapper...

Comment: Why not use a `std::string`?

Comment: There is only one "C++ standard", which currently is the one published in 2014. If you want to refer to a previous version, or a draft version, you should name it explicitly (e.g. "C++98" or "C++03" in your case). The publication of a standard supersedes the previous standard.

Comment: `std::vector` variable must be declared with a template parameter

Comment: it seems like you're unaware that the second line (with template parameter given) makes a copy of the buffer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create `vector<char>` of length 1024 and then use pointer to its first element as rawPtr. It will be no need to call `new` and `delete[]` then.

Comment: In this case, I prefer to keep the reference to the raw pointer because the method is very large and this raw pointer is used intensively (I want to do as less changes as I could). So, I would like to know if the std::vector assures that the pointer will be released, even if you have a reference to the raw pointer.

Comment: Yes, std::vector will release its memory in destructor, even if you still have any pointers to its elements

Comment: @Dan you can get a raw pointer by doing `&vec.front()`. This pointer will behave *exactly* like the raw pointer you have now, so you have exactly the same thing that you want.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` doesn't have a move constructor for `new`ed pointers. What happens, is that a copy is made for `std::vector`'s use. So you will still need to delete.

Comment: So, if I do `std::vector<char> a(new char[....]);` I still need a reference to the `new char[...]` to delete it? Is there any other way to perform the delete in a clean way?

Comment: @Dan this constructor does not exist. You cannot get a vector to manage an externally allocated array. This simply doesn't work. Make the vector allocate the array, and then use a pointer to that. It's what you want.

Comment: Yes sry, I referred to: char x = new char[X]; vector<char> a(x, x + X). In this case, the vector receives a copy like @stackptr says?

Comment: @Dan yes, always! The vector doesn't know what kind of iterators you pass in or how/if to manage them. It just copies the range.